# Positioning a container always on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, containers

I have a plugin in which I provide a simple div container and the plugin creates all kinds of `dom` elemnents inside the container through javascript. 
The basic structure that the plugin creates is something like this:

```
Wrapper Div (Position:Relative)
   - Left Container (Position: Absolute)
        - Left Top sub-container (Position: Absolute)
   - Right Container (Position: Relative)
        - Right Top sub-container (Position: Absolute)
        - Right Sub-Container frame with absolute items (Position: Relative)
```

Here's the fiddle I have created for the exact same structure that the plugin creates : **http://jsfiddle.net/FsYt8/**

The problem I am facing here is that when the content overflows, the content can be scrolled with the mouse wheel (as in fiddle). However, when I scroll down, I want the above two top left and right sub-container (red/blue bars) color in fiddle to remain at the top itself and not scroll down with the content.

The plugin creates dom elements inside `container-right-frame` div and positions the elements absolute (which are then positioned as per `container-right`'s top/left). How do I achieve the fixed kind of positioning for the above two bars?

Comment: Editted the link to fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Make the headers fixed and position them accordingly:

http://jsfiddle.net/QYCra/

Move the initial height of the columns down so they start under the headers:

```
.frame {width:924px;height:300px;position:relative;overflow-x:hidden;}
.axis-left {width:303px;height:34px;position:fixed; top:0; background-color:blue;z-index:2;}
.axis-right {width:615px;height:34px;position:fixed; top:0; left:310px; background-color:red;z-index:2;}
.container-left {height:340px;width:303px;top:30px; left:0px;position:absolute;background-color:green;z-index:1;overflow:hidden;}
.container-right {height:340px;width:615px;top:30px; left:304px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;background-color:yellow;z-index:1;}
```

Comment: The positioning part for these bars rests inside the plugin. So, if I decalre the position of the bars as fixed, how do I check where actually these should be placed? When I check in the debugger (inspect element), the bar actually goes out of the `frame` container and comes to the top of the page

Comment: I meant the bars that you see here are also generated by the plugin I made. `Frame` container is positioned relative on the page, the bars are generated through JavaScript and positioned as absolute by `frame.appendChild(barX)` . If I change the positioning of the barX or barY as `fixed`, I won't know the `top` and `left` position for the bar? How can I tackle that?

Comment: So, I think what you need is to make a separate scroll container for the columns?  Does that sound right?  One scroll for the page and one scroll for the frame columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the red and blue DIVs fixed and float them to the left. A left margin on the right DIV will adjust the x-axis location of the DIV as follows:

```
.frame {width:924px;height:300px;position:relative;overflow-x:hidden;}
.axis-left {float:left;width:303px;height:34px;position:fixed;background-color:blue;z-index:2;}
.axis-right {float:left;margin-left:305px;width:303px;height:34px;position:fixed;background-color:red;z-index:2;}
.container-left {height:340px;width:303px;left:0px;position:absolute;background-color:green;z-index:1;overflow:hidden;}
.container-right {height:340px;left:304px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.container-right-frame{
    position:relative;top:34px;background-color:yellow;z-index:1;width:615px;
}
```